# Media root set but thumbnails don't appear

Tags: python, django, gallery, sorl-thumbnail

In my project, Django (Django 1.8), I installed sorl-thumbnail.
But the thumbnails do not appear. I get the error:

In my console I get:

```
[22/Apr/2015 08:29:04]"GET /media/cache/fe/f7/fef79c8f9500649c7e8224abf81ce3b9.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1905
[22/Apr/2015 08:29:04]"GET /media/cache/25/a9/25a9bc15964015502d7bd8a048734c07.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1905
[22/Apr/2015 08:29:04]"GET /media/cache/a5/b6/a5b6b8f98ad045c9d6392feb41bc33ba.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1905
[22/Apr/2015 08:29:04]"GET /media/cache/20/fd/20fd944bdd086649f9d72d2117a46f67.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1905
[22/Apr/2015 08:29:04]"GET /media/cache/cf/b0/cfb07abdd25a38f3f0e092100c9888d5.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1905
[22/Apr/2015 08:29:04]"GET /media/cache/9c/2c/9c2ce4cb5cf17b937df293fecdaa4b10.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1905
```

**Part of my settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public_assets')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**My urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/', include("blog.urls", namespace="blog")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Code in template**

```
<table>
    {% for image in gallery %}
    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:3 %}<tr>{% endif %}

    {% thumbnail image "300x200" as im %}
    <td style="padding-left:50px;padding-right:50px;">
        <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}"><br>
        {{ image.title }}<br>
        {{ image.status }}<br>
        {{ image.price }}<br>
    </td>
    {% endthumbnail %}
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 or forloop.last %}</tr>{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `python manage.py thumbnail clear_delete_all`, maybe you have old links to cache images in DB.